# Clear additional rows when overwriting table data in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a daily task of overwriting data in a table. The number of rows fluctuates day-to-day, so I have to scroll to the bottom of the table to check if there are less rows than the overwritten data. If there are, I have to highlight the additional rows of "old" data and delete them. I'm trying to automate this process to either a) automatically delete old rows upon overwriting of table data or, b) create some sort of "alert" signaling there are old rows that need to be deleted. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Clear the table before overwriting the data.

Comment: ^^ using .CurrentRegion

Comment: I'm performing this function for 6 tables and having to scroll down and possibly delete rows for each is time consuming. If I can automate the row clearing I wouldn't have to take my hands off the keyboard to overwrite all 6 tables. When you do this every day the extra few minutes of savings does actually add up and I project I would be able to save around an hour a month by automating this.

Comment: I'll look into .currentregion, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I've created a macro and button to delete all rows from the 6 tables. Here is an example of the code that deletes all rows from one table. I copy and pasted this with/end with statement for each of the 6 tables into one macro.

```
With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table3")
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
End With
```